# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid[17.0.0]

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I downloaded LeafPic-master project( it is a gallery source code for Android studio)and try to change minsdkversion and targetSdkVersion( I what to install app on android 4.4 to newest android api), But I had some Error that I could not resolve them. what is solution?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven  { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven {  url  "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
    disable 'ExtraTranslation'
}
// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.0.46.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.2@aar'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.0.3@aar"
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.5.0'
    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.7'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.3.3'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0
```

Errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0].
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0].
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0].
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0].
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0].
Open File
Show Details
```

and Manifest.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.farasource.gallery">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />


        <uses-permission
            android:name="com.farasource.gallery.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>


        <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
            android:appComponentFactory="whateverString">
            <activity
                android:name=".PlayerActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/video_player"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="http" />
                    <data android:scheme="https" />
                    <data android:scheme="content" />
                    <data android:scheme="asset" />
                    <data android:scheme="file" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".IntroActivity"
                android:label="Intro Activity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreen"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.farasource.gallery.OPEN_ALBUM" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.albumsAct" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".PhotoPagerActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.albumPhoto" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.REVIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".SettingsActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTING" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".AboutActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABOUT" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".SecurityActivity"
                android:label="@string/security"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SECURITY" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ExcludedAlbumsActivity"
                android:label="@string/excluded_albums"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ExcludedAlbums" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.farasource.gallery.CustomGlideModule"
                android:value="GlideModule" />

            <activity android:name=".About" />
            <activity android:name=".OtherActivity"></activity>


            <receiver android:name="co.ronash.pushe.receiver.UpdateReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                    <data
                        android:path="com.farasource.gallery"
                        android:scheme="package" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                    <category android:name="com.farasource.gallery" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <meta-data android:name="co.ronash.pushe.token" android:value="PUSHE_375572161916"/>
            <meta-data android:name="co.ronash.pushe.cr" android:value="aHR0cDovLzdmOWRlNWQ0NzMyOTRhOTliNzU3ODk1MjMwYmQ4N2VkOjBkMmY2YWFiZjVmMjQ3YjdiY2NhOTJiMjBlYjdlN2FlQGNhLnB1c2hlLmlyLzYxNQ=="/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `google()` repo in the `repositories` block:

```
repositories {
    google()  //<---
    jcenter()
    maven  { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven {  url  "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
}
```

Comment: thank you dear. but i received New errors. i try migration to Androidx but some error occurred . such as "ERROR: Failed to resolve: fragment"

Comment: Hi @mohsenzarrindel.This is a separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question.

Comment: yes I asked a new separate question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075940/some-errors-after-migration-to-androidx)