# some Errors after migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, build.gradle

some errors after migration to AndroidX

I downloaded LeafPic-master project( it is a gallery source code for Android studio)and try to change minsdkversion and targetSdkVersion( I want to install my app on android 4.4 to newest android api).So I add the `google()` repo in the `repositories` to solve some problems then migrate to AndroidX.
the list of my errors is:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0]
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: fragment
Affected Modules: app
```

and my Build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven  { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven {  url  "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
    }
    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.0.46.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.2@aar'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.0.3@aar"
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.5.0'
    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.7'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.3'

    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.3.3'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
}
```

other Errors is:

```
cannot resolve symbole 'material' 
cannot resolve symbole 'appcompat'
cannot resolve symbole 'cardview'
cannot resolve symbole 'recyclerview'
```

in this lines:

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Comment: I'm not an expert like you were not an expert in the past. I'm a beginner and I know asking is better than not knowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
```

to

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a gradle issue.

Consider deleting gradle cache and retrying.

Gradle cache is at `C:\Users\yourUserName\.gradle\caches` (windows) or `~/.gradle/caches` (linux)

**Note:** If your area is under sanction, you must bypass this using proxy or VPN.

Answer (score 0):

At first, there is no need to inject the recyclerView's, CardView's and material libraries into the gradle file because in the android studio i.e. 3.4 and above all these libraries are already inserted by default. Just replace your this library -> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' with implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' and plus, go into the gradle.properties file and add this line -> "android.useAndroidX=true" and your project will work fine. In my case it worked.